AC Circuit Analysis - Thevenin and Norton Circuit
I am having a difficult time answering this exam question so I can asking for help. I've been asked to find the Thevenin equivalent in which I think I am correct.
When I convert to Norton I come astray especially when trying to find the load current and power at the load where it differs from the Thevenin.
Can someone look over the below and guide me in the right direction?




Welcome! Please inline your schematics.

For 17(1) isn't Eth just 10 * (10+j10) / ((10+j10)+(20-j20))? If so, then isn't the result 2 + j4? (I do get the same Zth.)
